# Typescript does not detect that property is a function

Tags: typescript, generics

I am using the [intl-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl-ts) library. The following function does not compile because it complains that `lang[result]` is not known to be executable:

```
function convertResult<
  T extends Messages &
    { [P in K]: (fieldName: string, p1: P1, p2: P2, p3: P3, p4: P4) => string },
  K extends keyof T,
  P1 = any,
  P2 = any,
  P3 = any,
  P4 = any
>(
  result: K | null,
  params: [P1, P2, P3, P4],
  lang?: Intl<T>,
  fieldName?: string
): boolean | string | null {
  if (result === null) {
    return lang ? null : true
  } else {
    if (lang) {
      return lang[result](fieldName, ...params)
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

I believed that the definition of `K` (type of `result`) would be enough for the compiler to know that `lang[result]` is indeed a method which takes the appropriate parameters.

So, I wonder if the problem is:

- something I missed in this code.
- something I missed in intl-ts (I am the maintainer of this package).
- or something too complex for Typescript and maybe I should open an issue for it.

A simple example is provided [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Messages%0D%0Atype%20MessageDirect%20%3D%20string%0D%0Atype%20MessageParams%3CP1%2C%20P2%2C%20P3%2C%20P4%2C%20P5%2C%20P6%3E%20%3D%20(arg1%3A%20P1%2C%20arg2%3A%20P2%2C%20arg3%3A%20P3%2C%20arg4%3A%20P4%2C%20arg5%3A%20P5%2C%20arg6%3A%20P6)%20%3D%3E%20string%0D%0Atype%20MessageFunction%3CT%20extends%20MessageDirect%20%7C%20MessageParams%3Cany%2C%20any%2C%20any%2C%20any%2C%20any%2C%20any%3E%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20string%0D%0A%20%20%3F%20()%20%3D%3E%20string%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20T%0D%0Ainterface%20Messages%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20MessageDirect%20%7C%20MessageParams%3Cany%2C%20any%2C%20any%2C%20any%2C%20any%2C%20any%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Intl%0D%0Ainterface%20IntlPrototype%3CT%20extends%20Messages%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20%24preferences%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3Cstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%24changePreferences(preferences%3A%20ReadonlyArray%3Cstring%3E%2C%20createGenerics%3F%3A%20boolean)%3A%20this%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20etc.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Atype%20IntlMessages%3CT%20extends%20Messages%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20MessageFunction%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Intl%3CT%20extends%20Messages%3E%20%3D%20IntlPrototype%3CT%3E%20%26%20IntlMessages%3CT%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20convertResult%3C%0D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20Messages%20%26%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20K%5D%3A%20(fieldName%3A%20string%2C%20p1%3A%20P1%2C%20p2%3A%20P2%2C%20p3%3A%20P3%2C%20p4%3A%20P4)%20%3D%3E%20string%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20P1%20%3D%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20P2%20%3D%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20P3%20%3D%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20P4%20%3D%20any%0D%0A%3E(%0D%0A%20%20result%3A%20K%20%7C%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20params%3A%20%5BP1%2C%20P2%2C%20P3%2C%20P4%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20lang%3F%3A%20Intl%3CT%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20fieldName%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A)%3A%20boolean%20%7C%20string%20%7C%20null%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(result%20%3D%3D%3D%20null)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20lang%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(lang)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20lang%5Bresult%5D(fieldName%2C%20...params)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20false%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Could you setup simple example in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)  to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The `Messages &` is the part that is causing problems. What does that interface contain ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Please look at [Messages source code](https://github.com/sveyret/intl-ts/blob/master/src/Messages.ts)

Comment: @AlekseyL. I edited the question to add a link to playground example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is cause because of the intersection with `Messages`. Typescript will not properly infer the corect type for the index access because of it.

In this particular case I would just  remove the intersection. Don't think it servers a major role, it just restates that `T` must contain function or strings, the mapped type you use to constrain `T` is much more restrictive, so if an object conforms to the constraint of  `T` it will conform to `Messgaes`,

```
function convertResult<
    T extends { [P in K]: (fieldName: string, p1: P1, p2: P2, p3: P3, p4: P4) => string },
    K extends keyof T,
    P1 = any,
    P2 = any,
    P3 = any,
    P4 = any
    >(
        result: K | null,
        params: [P1, P2, P3, P4],
        lang?: T,
        fieldName?: string
    ): boolean | string | null {
    if (result === null) {
        return lang ? null : true
    } else {
        if (lang) {
            return lang[result](fieldName, ...params)
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well by both removing `Messages` and modifying `lang` to directly be of type `T`. Anyway, I would say it is a bug in Typescript compiler and requires an issue. Do you think the same?

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret I think it's a bit more complicated.. there are lots of problems when you want to go from generics to concrete types inside a function .. I would have expected it work, but I expect a lot of things to work and they don't always work because of other constraints. I definitely think it's work a github issue to get an official possition

Comment: I'll open an issue then, and let the team decide if it should be corrected or not. Thank you.